# mouse click issue with Infragistics UltraComboEditor

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultracombo

I am using a control from Infragistics called "UltraComboEditor". I am having an issue where I want to click in the text area of the combobox editor and select all the text. I've tried down,up,click mouse events but it will not trigger. What will trigger is the mouse down when I click on the down arrow to drop down the items in the control. Can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Assume "ultraComboEditor1" is your ultra combo). Try the following code (you can write it in constructor):

ultraComboEditor1.DropDownStyle = Infragistics.Win.DropDownStyle.DropDown;